# Insertar varios datos en una tabla a la vez

Tags: genexus

Buen día muchachos.
estoy trabajando con Genexus 15 con JAVA y vengo de nuevo con otra interrogante y es que deseo crear en un Web Panel una grilla parecida a esta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual me permita ingresar varios datos en una tabla con un solo botón y si podría hacerlo sin necesidad de insertar el código de cada dato que estoy ingresando.
Esta es mi tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo entendido que es con una Grilla, pero no se como ponerlo en mi Web Panel, si con variables o atributos y como insertar una linea nueva.

Espero no causar molestias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer es que un WebPanel haga de Insert para una transacción de 2 niveles. Lamento decirte que para esto es muy complicado controlar el tema de la Grilla, ya que debes controlar algunas cosas. De las cuales debes considerar.

- Debes trabajar con variales.
- La grilla al no tener una navegación va a generar una sola fila y no te va a funcionar asignandole **rows** a la misma.
- Deberas generar procedimientos que te ayuden con el insert a la base, por la transacción padre y el **for each line** del grid que deberás barrer para generar cada insert del hijo.

Como ves es engorroso, ya que es posible que debas recurrir hasta a SDT's para que almacenen brevemente los datos.

**Mi recomendación**

Utiliza una **Transacción**, estas fueron creadas para trabajar al cien el CRUD de tus entidades. En caso de no poder modelar el **Form** de la transacción que ya tienes, solo basta con guardrar una nueva a partir de esta, como lo haces:

- Abres la transacción.
- Click derecho en la pestaña de la misma.
- Save As...
- El nombre que desees. Y listo.

Esta es una copia de la transacción que ya tienes (alumno), pero esta va a hacer como tu formulario perzonalizado para cierta situación. Y en ella si puedes manejar a tu antojo el Grid y los eventos de commit y demás.

Espero haberte guiado por el camino adecuado y que te ayude mas que nada la respuesta a aclarar que en este tipo de situaciones debes usar transacciones. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda Rostan, voy a intentar como me indicas y te comento como me fue.
Saludos ¡¡

Comment: De nada @AngelCayhualla ungusto ayudarte. Estamos en contacto!